# How to change the default typography in vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

These are the default typography available in vuetify 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/typography/.

How can I add few more font-sizes with my custom inputs to my vuetify project? Currently, I am only able to update the given font-sizes by updating them in the variables.scss file by this code

```
$headings: (
    "subtitle-1": (
        "size": 93px,
        "weight": 400,
        "line-height": 1.75rem,
        "letter-spacing": 0.009375em,
        "font-family": $body-font-family,
    ),
);
```

But since 'subtitle-1' is an already available typography, I am able to change it. Can I add some custom typography in it?

Answer (score 0):

create a folder called scss and create a file called `variables.scss` in my case I use Montserrat

paste this

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

$body-font-family: 'Montserrat';
$font-size-root: 14px !default;
```

finally in your global file (APP.vue) paste this

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "./scss/variables.scss";



v-app {
  font-family: $body-font-family !important;
}

</style>
```

as a recommendation use the `!important`